# SELECT * FROM table A and get values corresponding rows in Table B that match a specific field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables says, `Quiz` & `Winners`

```
Quiz Table:
id name      pub_date   type   theme
1  bday quiz 2014-01-03 random fun

Winners Table:
id quizId winner points match_date
1  1      Nick   100    2016-02-29
2  1      Mick   156    2016-03-04
3  1      Sara   199    2016-03-06

-> `quizId` references to `id` in Quiz Table
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get a quiz & its winners in a single html sortable table row like this:

```
id name       pub_date   type    theme 2016-03-06 2016-03-05 2016-03-04 ...
1  bday quiz  2014-01-03  random fun    199                   156
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT Quiz.id,Quiz.name,Quiz.pub_date,Quiz.type,Quiz.theme,Winners.winner 
FROM Quiz,Winners 
WHERE Quiz.id = Winners.quizId AND 
Quiz.pub_date > '2015-03-01' AND  
Quiz.pub_date < '2016-03-06' AND 
Winners.match_date > '2016-02-01' AND 
Winners.match_date < '2016-03-06' 
ORDER BY Winners.points DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

**This method works very well except that the LIMIT condition returns 100 rows while I need 100 quizzes & their winners and also duplicates content.**

Another method on my mind is to call each 100 quiz rows first & get winners for each quiz, in that case, I cannot sort quizzes by Winners's  points.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code (in this instance, a simple PHP loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all the winners for 100 matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM Quiz AS q
JOIN (
  SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, q2.id, z.p AS m, z.mp AS n
  FROM Quiz AS q2
  JOIN
  ( SELECT MAX(w.points) AS p, w.quizId AS mp
    FROM Winners AS w
    WHERE w.match_date BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2016-03-06'
    GROUP BY w.quizId
  ) AS z ON z.mp = q2.id, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
) AS u ON u.id = q.id
JOIN Winners AS w2 ON w2.quizId = n
WHERE rank <= 2 AND m = points
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c6d8/2

If you want to change it to 100 . You need to modify the `rank <= 2`.
I just want to figure out that it works with 2 quizzes.

Comment: HI Varon, This has same problem as the one I already have. I don't want to limit no. of rows to 100. I want to limit no. of quizzes to 100. For example, for the above query, it returns top 100 rows with matched criteria but not 100 quizzes as most data will be duplicate with different dates.

Comment: Both our snippets would work if I use LIMIT 100*no._days_difference. For example, in above example the days difference is 1101 days. Therefore using, LIMIT 110100 would give what we need but, I guess, that is a very bad way.

Comment: 100 Quizzes means: The Top 100 score-values overall **OR** you have 100 quizzes ordered by date and therefore i want the top-scores and their users?

Comment: Basically, I need 100 distinct rows from Quiz table with all their winners&points in the mentioned date range.

Comment: So, it will be more than 100 rows overall as there will be multiple rows with same quiz id & different dates.

Comment: Does it works for you now? I just want to tell a last sentence: You can let MySQL EXPLAIN the query ... and then you can see that the performance is not high-end. If it is not okay, you can join quiz also to the inner script with your WHERE, but I think there is no way to skip the double-inner-select. Usually you should make more selects or filter it by the calling software.

Comment: That Worked Varon. I'll work on it. Thank you so much for your time. :)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try this:

```
SELECT Quiz.id,Quiz.name,Quiz.pub_date,Quiz.type,Quiz.theme,Winners.winner 
FROM Quiz as Quiz
INNER JOIN Winners as Winners ON Quiz.id =  Winners.quizId
WHERE 
Quiz.pub_date > '2015-03-01' AND  
Quiz.pub_date < '2016-03-06' AND 
Winners.match_date > '2016-02-01' AND 
Winners.match_date < '2016-03-06' 
GROUP BY Winners.id
ORDER BY Winners.points DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Not sure with the output of this and haven't checked the code

Comment: Hi Louis, Just tried that. It gives same result as mine. It returns 100 rows but what I need is top 100 distinct quizzes matching the criteria.

Comment: Any idea, if we can make use of DISTINCT here?

Answer (score -3):

Try by addind distinct after select. it will eliminate duplicate rows from selected rows set.

```
SELECT distinct Quiz.id,Quiz.name,Quiz.pub_date,Quiz.type,Quiz.theme,Winners.winner 
FROM Quiz,Winners 
WHERE Quiz.id = Winners.quizId AND 
Quiz.pub_date > '2015-03-01' AND  
Quiz.pub_date < '2016-03-06' AND 
Winners.match_date > '2016-02-01' AND 
Winners.match_date < '2016-03-06' 
ORDER BY Winners.points DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: You just copied  the snippet from the question

Comment: I added the "distint"  that eliminates duplicated rows from a qyery result.